# text on image in header

Tags: html, css, image, text, header

I have a header.php that I am trying to create a menu for.  The "menu" consists of 3 colored boxes and in those color boxes I'd like to put the text that links to the other pages. No matter what I try I simply can't get the text in the colored boxes (images).  This is what I have so far for the "base code".

```
    <html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/header_media/header.css" type="text/css" />

<body>



<!--THIS IS THE LOGO-->
<div id="logo"> 
<img src="/header_media/GTextured.png" width="75" height="50" hspace="0" vspace="0"/>
</div>

<div id="logo"> 
<img src="/header_media/shapeimage.png" style="position: relative; top: -40px; left: 90px;">
</div>




<!--THIS IS THE MENU SYSTEM-->
<div>
<div id="menu">
<img src="/header_media/red.png" width="100" height="25" style="position: relative; top: -40px; left: 300px;">
<img src="/header_media/green.png" width="100" height="25" style="position: relative; top: -40px; left: 301px;">
<img src="/header_media/blue.png" width="100" height="25" style="position: relative; top: -40px; left: 302px;">
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Well, to start, what can't you do?

Comment: I can't get the text in the colored boxes/images. Edited post. Thank you.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be any text in the snippet you've posted. Do red, green and blue.png have text on them?

Comment: I removed the text from the code because I knew it was wrong. So this is just the code with the text not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="menu" style="margin:auto; width:300px; height:25px;">
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; height:25px; background-image:/header_media/red.png; text-align:center;">test</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; height:25px; background-image:/header_media/green.png; text-align:center;">test</div>
    <div style="float:left; width:100px; height:25px; background-image:/header_media/blue.png; text-align:center;">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, did some tweaking and worked well. How would I put a small space in between the colored boxes? like maybe just around 5px?

Comment: Set the menu div a little bigger and give the button divs a margin on the left or right as needed.

Answer (score 0):

You are approaching the problem incorrectly. An image displayed using the `<img />` tag is an element. This means it takes up space. It looks like you are then trying to shoehorn text in on top of them.

There is a much better way which is using a background image on an element that is made to hold text. From your code it looks like you want the three boxes to be next to each other. This involves positioning the content. Using relative positioning as you are seems like a bad idea. It is likely to break. Take ten minutes and read an article on css positioning. static, absolute, relative and floats.

Something like this will work better. Float the elements left so that they sit next to one another. Then clear them when done so later content appears where it should. Finally set a background using the css url property. In this case I just put in colors, but left in the syntax where you could specify the image if you wanted to.

http://jsfiddle.net/FUZDW/

```
div { height: 50px; width: 100px; border: 1px solid black; }
div#menu1 { background: red url('pathToImage'); }
div#menu2 { background: green; }
div#menu3 { background: blue; }

div.menu { float: left; }

<div class="menu" id="menu1">red</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu2">green</div>
<div class="menu" id="menu3">blue</div>
<br style="clear: both;" />
my page content
```